# Click event in drilldown chart - Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, angular-highcharts

I am working on an app where I need to show drilldown chart. I am using highcharts for this, I want to fire the click event when user clicks on the bars of second chart (drilled one).

I am using code but this is firing the event on the first chart also. Is there a way to fire it on the second chart only? or check if event is raised from which chart?

```
 plotOptions: {
    series: {
        events:{
              click: function (event) {
               
                console.log(event);
                   alert("testing" + event.point.name)
                
              }
        }
    }
  }
```

Sample is here - https://highcharts-angular-drilldown-zqmyd9.stackblitz.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to define your chart as a global variable and add the condition to check if the chart.drilldownUpButton exists into your click callback.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uhbored9/

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      events: {
        click: function(event) {
            if (chart.drillUpButton) {
                alert("testing" + event.point.name)
           }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```